# How do I Distribute and Layout 9 digits Evenly Throughout a JavaFX Panel

Tags: layout, text, javafx-8

I am trying to get 9 digits to distribute evenly, in three rows, throughout a box of a defined size, without the numbers clumping up in the middle.

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

So far, the only consistent way that I have found to prevent the numbers from clumping up in the middle, is to add two extra spaces to the digit in the middle, one extra space character on each side (ex: " 2 ", " 5 " and " 8 ").  Surely there is a better way to layout these numbers than this?

public class DemoCode extends Application {

```
   // Private Class    
   class PossibleCellValue extends Text {

      PossibleCellValue(String value) {
         super(value);
         setFont(FONT_FOR_POSSIBLE_VALUES);
      }
    }

    // Private Class
    class Cell extends VBox {
        Cell() {
            super();   
            this.setBorder(borderBlack);
            this.setPrefSize(CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
            PossibleCellValue guess1 = new PossibleCellValue("1");
            PossibleCellValue guess2 = new PossibleCellValue(" 2 ");
            PossibleCellValue guess3 = new PossibleCellValue("3");
            PossibleCellValue guess4 = new PossibleCellValue("4");
            PossibleCellValue guess5 = new PossibleCellValue(" 5 ");
            PossibleCellValue guess6 = new PossibleCellValue("6");
            PossibleCellValue guess7 = new PossibleCellValue("7");
            PossibleCellValue guess8 = new PossibleCellValue(" 8 ");
            PossibleCellValue guess9 = new PossibleCellValue("9");
            HBox box1 = new HBox(guess1, guess2, guess3);
            HBox box2 = new HBox(guess4, guess5, guess6);
            HBox box3 = new HBox(guess7, guess8, guess9);
            VBox vbox = new VBox(box1, box2, box3);
            getChildren().add(vbox);
            this.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        }
    }

    // Normal start method
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Cell());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Demo Code");
        stage.show();
    } // DemoCode

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    static protected final BorderStroke strokeBlack = new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderStroke.THIN);
    public static final Border          borderBlack = new Border(strokeBlack);

    private static final int   FONT_SIZE_FOR_POSSIBLE_VALUES   = 15;
    private static final Font  FONT_FOR_POSSIBLE_VALUES        = Font.font("Courier", FontWeight.NORMAL, FONT_SIZE_FOR_POSSIBLE_VALUES);
    static protected final int CELL_SIZE                       = 54;

} // DemoCode.java
```

Comment: Question was cross-posted to an Oracle forum and answered there: [Distribute and Layout 9 digits Evenly Throughout a Panel](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3996086)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [TilePane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html) or [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) for your layout.

Here is an example using a TilePane:

[image: grid]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class GridViewer extends Application {

    private static final int S = 3;
    private static final double PANE_SIZE = 54 * S;

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TilePane tiles = new TilePane(
                0, 0,
                IntStream.range(1, 10)
                        .mapToObj(this::createGridCell)
                        .toArray(Node[]::new)
        );

        tiles.setMinSize(TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE, TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        tiles.setMaxSize(TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE, TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        tiles.setPrefSize(PANE_SIZE, PANE_SIZE);
        tiles.setPrefColumns(S);
        tiles.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
        tiles.setPrefTileHeight(PANE_SIZE / S);
        tiles.setPrefTileWidth(PANE_SIZE / S);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(tiles);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    private Node createGridCell(int i) {
        Label label = new Label("" + i);
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cyan; -fx-border-color: green;");

        label.setPrefSize(PANE_SIZE / S, PANE_SIZE / S);
        label.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);

        return label;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you.  This is a very nice, and concise solution.  However, when I set the Min/Max size to anything except TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE, or if I setPrefSize(54, 54), the preferred column count of (3) is ignored by the layout manager.  My intent is to use this as a cell, within a Sudoku game, so having a rectangular shape is important.

Comment: My answer does provide a rectangular shape.  I don't understand your issue.  GridPane provides additional constraint possibilities over TilePane, so you may choose to use that instead.

Comment: I misspoke.  I meant to say, the shape needs to be a square of a particular size.

Comment: When I attempted to apply your example, the layout manager no longer honored the 3 column restraint. This was when I attempt to explicitly set the size of the box by replacing this code ...
<pre><code>
     tiles.setMinSize(TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE, TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
     tiles.setMaxSize(TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE, TilePane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
</code></pre>
with a specific, predefined size ...
<pre><code>
     tiles.setMinSize(54, 54);
     tiles.setMaxSize(54, 54);</code></pre>

Comment: I updated the example to demonstrate how to define "the shape needs to be a square of a particular size" as you requested in your comment.

Comment: I am going to have to play with this a bit (and I will probably end up refactoring my entire code base), but this does a very nice job of laying out the numbers in a square, with a defined size.  

I particularly appreciated the two demonstrations of a programming idiom that I am seeing more and more of ... which is using the new streams classes, lambda's, and the builder pattern together to solve a problem in a single line of very concise, very dense code.

Comment: For those who are interested, an alternative solution was posted at [Distribute and Layout 9 digits Evenly Throughout a Panel](https://community.oracle.com/message/14146736#14146736), on an Oracle JavaFX forum that defined a custom layout manager.